# eines used as an article for plural nouns...?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Eine ärtzliche Anamnese erhebt mithilfe der Erinnerungen eines **Patienten** dessen Krankheitsgeschichte,...

If it's "eines", why is it "Patienten"? I believe it should either be that:

Eines becomes einer

Or

Patienten becomes patientes

Is this sentence wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Nouns ending in a consonant, sometimes have the genitive with "-en": "der Psychologe/des Psychologen".  Sadly you have to learn this case by case. Example: "der Tor" (= the stupid person) -> "des Toren", but "das Tor" (the gate) -> des Tores/des Tors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If it's "eines", why is it "Patienten"?

It is the *Genitiv* of "Patient":

> ein/der Patient (Nominativ)
> eines/des Patienten (Genitiv)
> einem/dem Patient(en) (Dativ)
> einen/den Patient(en) (Akkusativ)

Notice, that the bracketed endings in Dativ and Akkusativ tend to be omitted. This is not correct but common practice.

Answer (score 1):

German nouns are declined not only by number, but also by case. There are two numbers (singular and plural) and 4 cases (nominative, genitive, dative and accusative) which gives 8 different combinations.

There is no noun, that has 8 different endings in these 8 combinations, so very often there are combinations that have identical endings, but which combinations are equal, and which are different, and what the specific ending is for a given combination, depends on the noun.

When you learn a German noun, you need not only to learn which gender it has, but you also need to learn, to which declension class it belongs.

Words, that end in nominative case singular in -ent (like *Student*, but also *Dozent, Klient, Präsident* and many others), belong to the class **W1**. The letter *W* stands for *weak and mixed declension.* There are 4 week declension classes and 6 strong declension classes, and there is a Wikipedia article about [Deutsche Deklination](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination) where you can read details, but also your grammar textbook should provide these informations.

Here are the declensions for the class W1, to which the masculine noun *Student* belongs:

- Singular

  - Nominativ
    Subjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Der Student schläft.
    > Ein Student schläft.

    Gleichsetzungsnominativ, definit und indefinit

    > Herr Müller ist der Student.
    > Herr Müller ist ein Student.
  - Genitiv
    Genitivattribut eines anderen Substantivs, definit und indefinit

    > Das ist die Wohnung des Studenten.
    > Das ist die Wohnung eines Studenten.

    Gentivobjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Der Professor erbarmt sich des Studenten.
    > Der Professor erbarmt sich eines Studenten.
  - Dativ
    Dativobjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Das Buch gehört dem Studenten.
    > Das Buch gehört einem Studenten.
  - Akkusativ
    Akkusativobjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Ich sehe den Studenten.
    > Ich sehe einen Studenten.
- Plural

  - Nominativ
    Subjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Die Studenten schlafen.
    > Studenten schlafen.

    Gleichsetzungsnominativ, definit und indefinit

    > Herr Müller und Frau Schuster sind die Studenten.
    > Herr Müller und Frau Schuster sind Studenten.
  - Genitiv
    Genitivattribut eines anderen Substantivs, nur definit<sup>1</sup>

    > Das ist die Wohnung der Studenten.

    Gentivobjekt, nur definit<sup>1</sup>

    > Der Professor erbarmt sich der Studenten.
  - Dativ
    Dativobjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Das Buch gehört den Studenten.
    > Das Buch gehört Studenten.
  - Akkusativ
    Akkusativobjekt, definit und indefinit

    > Ich sehe die Studenten.
    > Ich sehe Studenten.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The indefinite form of Genitive plural needs a mandatory determiner, for example a numeral. So this is possible: *»Das ist die Wohnung zweier Studenten.« »Der Professor erbarmt sich zweier Studenten.«* But in all other cases, a determiner is optional. Especially there is no article in all indefinite plural forms.</sub>

Comment: A verbose answer that does little to help a language learner. Have a look at newer editions of the Duden grammar to see that things are actually much simpler than Wikipedia makes them out to be. Also I don't get why one would use a list that spans multiple screens worth of space instead of a table